# What's the difference between the write() and typewrite() functions in pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've seen the use of `pyautogui.typewrite()` but I can't find the documentation for it in the pyautogui docs. I did find the `pyautogui.write()` function in the docs and I wanted to know if they are the same thing, because from what I can see, they seem very similar.

Comment: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/e869e5dd9c36022631888555776749ca2f70382b/pyautogui/__init__.py#L1644

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of [version 1.0](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/e869e5dd9c36022631888555776749ca2f70382b/pyautogui/__init__.py#L1644) there is no difference between `write` and `typewrite`. The `write` function has been chosen as the preferred invocation but currently `write` is just an alias for `typewrite`:

```
write = typewrite  # In PyAutoGUI 1.0, write() replaces typewrite().
```

Answer (score 1):

The **typewrite()** function is used to type something in a text field.
in the other side the **write()** function does the same thing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).